# Get data from database with condition and show it in a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[This is the data that I have in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukCST.jpg)

[This is what I want to make in the view.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f4fA.jpg)

What I want to do is I want to get the data from the database, if the data inside the column is 1, I want to get the column name as you can see in image 2, but there could be more than 1 column name because the column with data can be column A,B,C... etc.. and I want to show the student name and the subject (a,b,c... etc) if the data in it is '1' in the view. I stuck on how to get all those subject A,B,C.. this is the code that I have written, but it is incomplete because I don't know what to add on it to make it as what I have mentioned above. Hopefully, someone can help me. Thanks in advance

```
if($row->'A'=='1'){i dont know what should i put here so that i cant get the column name 'A' and print it in view.blade.php}
```

Comment: You can simply display the column name if the value of that column is 1 like `@if($row->A == 1) 
    A
@endif`    
or you could use ternary operator like `{{$row->A==1 ? 'A,' : ' ' }}`    
Check this condition manually for each column like `{{$row->B==1 ? 'B,' : ' ' }}` `{{$row->C==1 ? 'C,' : ' ' }}` and so on.

Comment: @Xitish for the {{$row->A==1 ? 'A,' : ' ' }} should i put something in the empty : ' ' }}

Comment: it works like a charm :), thank you @Xintish

Comment: You should not have such logic in view, you should get structured data directly from the controller so you can use it directly. It will make the blade files much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table in database is `student_details`, create an eloquent model `StudentDetail` inside `app/models/StudentDetail.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StudentDetail extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'student_details';

    /**
     * Get subjects in the view
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSubjects()
    {
        $subjects = [];
        $subjects[] = $this->A == 1 ? 'A' : null;
        $subjects[] = $this->B == 1 ? 'B' : null;
        $subjects[] = $this->C == 1 ? 'C' : null;
        $subjects = array_filter($subjects);

        return implode(',', $subjects);
    }

}
```

Then you can retrieve data in your controller :

```
public function view()
{
    $studentDetails = StudentDetail::get();

    return view('view.path', compact('studentDetails'));
}
```

And inside view you can do :

```
@foreach($studentDetails as $detail)

    {{ $detail->name }} : {{ $detail->getSubjects() }}
@endforeach
```

You can use appended property as well, I have not used that because appended property is added every-time when model is instantiated. I believe having it in a function makes it flexible to use as and when needed.

Comment: Your suggestion was superb, thanks for helping me for the 2nd time in this week :), I do really appreciate it :) :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: how can I save the data generated to the database? I have tried to add this code     DB::table('finalyear_students')
            ->updateOrInsert(
                ['student_name'=>$finalyear_students->student_name],
                ['subject'=>$finalyear_students->getSubjects()]);     but it doesnt work..

Comment: Are you casting subject field as an array in eloquent model? because I think you have different column for each subject right?

Comment: yea I have a different column for each of the subject, but the models return an array right? or I still can save the subject based on the column? I'm new in Laravel .. not much thing I know and I don't have any idea on how to save the data actually. It would be great if I can save each subject on a different column instead of a collection of subjects in a single column

Comment: how can I save the subject produced by the getsubjects() function in the model to the database? I wish you could show me cause I don't have any idea on how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Okay i tried it bit different way it's not proper but it will give you desired output you want :-

```
Route::get('/test',function(){
    $query = TestTable::all();
    $calculateData = [];
    foreach ($query as $key){
        $subjects = '';
        if($key->A === 1){
            $subjects .= 'A';
        }
        if($key->B === 1){
            $subjects .= 'B';
        }
        if($key->C === 1){
            $subjects .= 'C';
        }
        $calculateData[] = [$key->name,$subjects];
    }
    foreach ($calculateData as $key){
        dump("NAME : " . $key[0]."Subject : " . $key[1]);
    }
    dd("STOP");
})->name('test');
```

Comment: you accepted it first i was in the air then you unaccepted it...i'm back to normal :p

Comment: I wish I could accept more than 1 answer, but I can't :(, I do really appreciate your effort to help me, bro :)

Comment: You can upvote it, if it works and yeah anytime bro, That's what dev's DO

Comment: done :) upvote your suggestion but my rep < 15 so it doesn't appear

Comment: ohh don't worry that's okay you'll get up in no time :) Happy Coding