# Show data with certain condition only in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have a problem where I don't know how to show the subject where the sum '>0', I managed to show all of the subjects, but it shows with the subject that has sum '0' too. I'm not sure where to put the condition code, is it in view or controller.

this is my controller

```
public function showSubjectListFinalYear(){
     $t1  = DB::table('matrices')->where('total_subject_left','<',10)->sum('teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat');
     $t2  = DB::table('matrices')->where('total_subject_left','<',10)->sum('struktur_diskrit');
     $t3  = DB::table('matrices')->where('total_subject_left','<',10)->sum('teknik_pengaturcaraan_1');
     $t4  = DB::table('matrices')->where('total_subject_left','<',10)->sum('logik_digital');

     return view('admin.final_year_subject_list')>with(compact('t1','t2','t3','t4'));
}
```

this is the code in my view

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Subject name</th>
        <th>No. of students</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Teknologi dan Sistem Maklumat</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t1 }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Struktur diskrit</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t2 }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Teknik Pengaturcaraan 1</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t3 }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Logik Digital</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t4 }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from database with condition and show it in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909046/get-data-from-database-with-condition-and-show-it-in-a-view)

Comment: Always try and put logic in your controller

Comment: thank you for giving a suggestion, really appreciate it..

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
$t1  = matrices::where('total_subject_left','>',10)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->sum('teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat');
```

it will show you subject with sum greater than 10. if you replace 10 with 0 it will show subjects with sum greater than 0
assuming you are using

use/app/model name

Comment: what my codes in controller do is get all data that have value of total_subject_left <10 then it will sum the value in column 'teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat' and show the subject name and value of sum in view.blade.php. it does what I want, but I dont want to show the subject name and the sum value if the sum value = 0. I'm thinking to put if else at the blade file but I think there's better way to do it because some of this group member told me that the logic should be in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this issue by adding this code at view.blade file

```
                    @if($t1>0)
                      <tr class="gradeX">
                         <td>Teknologi dan Sistem Maklumat</td>
                         <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t1 }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    @endif
```